ValueError: Total of weights must be finite
I am trying to create a classification algorithm using Graph Neural Networks (GNNs) in Python, but I am encountering an error that I can't resolve.
I have already tried removing NaN values from my dataframe, but the issue persists. Below is the code I am using.
If anyone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it!
Here is the function I use to create a graph from a dataframe row:
# Função para criar um grafo a partir de uma linha do dataframe
def criar_grafo_passe(row, index):
    G = nx.Graph()

    passer = f"Player_PP"  # Identificador único para o jogador que passa a bola
    receiver = f"Player_PR"  # Identificador único para o jogador que recebe a bola em t0
    receiver_t1 = f"Player_PRt1"  # Identificador único para o jogador que recebe a bola em t1
    opponent_pp = f"Opponent_PP"  # Identificador único para o oponente mais próximo do passador
    opponent_pr = f"Opponent_PR"  # Identificador único para o oponente mais próximo do receptor em t0
    opponent_pr_t1 = f"Opponent_PRt1"  # Identificador único para o oponente mais próximo do receptor em t1
    distance = row['Passing distance']  # Distância do passe

    # Adiciona nós para passador, receptor, receptor em t1 e oponentes mais próximos
    G.add_node(passer, role='passer')
    G.add_node(receiver, role='receiver')
    G.add_node(receiver_t1, role='receiver_t1')
    G.add_node(opponent_pp, role='opponent')
    G.add_node(opponent_pr, role='opponent')
    G.add_node(opponent_pr_t1, role='opponent')

    # Adiciona arestas entre passador e receptor
    G.add_edge(passer, receiver, weight=distance)

    # Adiciona arestas entre passador e oponente mais próximo
    G.add_edge(passer, opponent_pp, weight=row['Nearest opp. PPt0'])

    # Adiciona arestas entre receptor e oponente mais próximo em t0 e t1
    G.add_edge(receiver, opponent_pr, weight=row['Nearest opp. PRt0'])
    G.add_edge(receiver_t1, opponent_pr_t1, weight=row['Nearest opp. PRt1'])

    # Adiciona aresta entre receptor em t0 e t1
    G.add_edge(receiver, receiver_t1, weight=row['Displacement PR'])

    # Adiciona atributos aos nós do passador
    G.nodes[passer].update({
        'Foot or not': row['Foot or not'],
        'Nearest opp. PPt0': row['Nearest opp. PPt0'],
        'Velocity nearest opp. PPt0': row['Velocity nearest opp. PPt0'],
        'Opponet angle': row['Opponet angle'],
        'Density PPt0': [row['Density PPt0 (1m)'], row['Density PPt0 (2m)'], row['Density PPt0 (5m)'], row['Density PPt0 (10m)']],
        'Velocity PPt0': row['Velocity PPt0'],
        'Distance PPt0 to target': row['Distance PPt0 to target']
    })

    # Adiciona atributos aos nós do receptor em t0
    G.nodes[receiver].update({
        'Nearest opp. PRt0': row['Nearest opp. PRt0'],
        'Density PRt0': [row['Density PRt0 (1m)'], row['Density PRt0 (2m)'], row['Density PRt0 (5m)'], row['Density PRt0 (10m)']],
        'Velocity PRt0': row['Velocity PRt0'],
        'Distance PRt0 to target': row['Distance PRt0 to target']
    })

    # Adiciona atributos aos nós do receptor em t1
    G.nodes[receiver_t1].update({
        'Nearest opp. PRt1': row['Nearest opp. PRt1'],
        'Density PRt1': [row['Density PRt1 (1m)'], row['Density PRt1 (2m)'], row['Density PRt1 (5m)'], row['Density PRt1 (10m)']],
        'Velocity PRt1': row['Velocity PRt1'],
        'Distance PRt1 to target': row['Distance PRt1 to target'],
        'Out ball angle': row['Out ball angle']
    })

    # Adiciona atributos aos nós dos oponentes mais próximos
    G.nodes[opponent_pp].update({
        'role': 'opponent',
        'distance to passer': row['Nearest opp. PPt0']
    })

    G.nodes[opponent_pr].update({
        'role': 'opponent',
        'distance to receiver t0': row['Nearest opp. PRt0']
    })

    G.nodes[opponent_pr_t1].update({
        'role': 'opponent',
        'distance to receiver t1': row['Nearest opp. PRt1']
    })

    # Adiciona atributos à aresta entre passador e receptor
    G[passer][receiver].update({
        'Passing distance': row['Passing distance'],
        'Ball velocity': row['Ball velocity'],
        'Passing angle': row['Passing angle'],
        'Ball progression': row['Ball progression'],
        'Outplayed opp. ': row['Outplayed opp. '],
        'Opp. btw PRt1 and target': row['Opp. btw PRt1 and target'],
        'Accuracy': row['Accuracy'],
        'One touth': row['One touth']
    })

    return G

# Remover valores NaN ou infinitos do dataframe
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)

# Criar uma lista de grafos, um para cada passe
grafos_passes = [criar_grafo_passe(row, index) for index, row in df.iterrows()]

# Treinar o algoritmo Node2Vec em cada grafo
embeddings = []
for G in grafos_passes:
    # Verificar e remover qualquer peso não finito do grafo
    for u, v, data in G.edges(data=True):
        if not np.isfinite(data.get("weight", 1.0)):
            G.remove_edge(u, v)

    # Configurar e treinar o modelo Node2Vec
    node2vec = Node2Vec(G, dimensions=64, walk_length=30, num_walks=200, workers=4)
    model = node2vec.fit(window=10, min_count=1)

    # Obter os embeddings dos nós
    node_embeddings = {node: model.wv[node] for node in G.nodes}
    embeddings.append(node_embeddings)

# Converter os embeddings em um dataframe
df_embeddings = pd.DataFrame(embeddings)

# Separar os dados em recursos (X) e rótulos (y)
X = df_embeddings.values
y = df['Difficulty'].values  # Substitua 'Difficulty' pelo nome da coluna que contém os rótulos de dificuldade

# Dividir os dados em conjuntos de treinamento e teste
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Treinar o classificador Random Forest
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Fazer previsões
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

# Avaliar o desempenho do classificador
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print("Acurácia do Random Forest:", accuracy)



I have checked and cleaned the data to remove NaNs and infinite values. I also reviewed the graph construction logic and the attributes for nodes and edges. Despite this, I encounter problems when training the Node2Vec model and using the embeddings to train a Random Forest classifier.
Any suggestions on how to debug or fix this issue?
Thank you!

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

Please read: How to debug small programs and What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?
